# For loop inside ComponentDidMount to iterate through an object not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a prop called notes which is a multi-tier object (like json) and coming from some parent. When I try to iterate through it inside ComponentDidMount, it seemingly doesn't go inside for loop, as the console log is not outputting anything. Anything I'm missing?

```js
class NotesList extends React.Component {

  state = {
    arr: []
  }
  
  static defaultProps = {
    notes: {
      tier1: {
        tier2: "some content 1",
        tier22: "some 2"
      },
      tier11: {
        tier222: "some content 1",
        tier2222: "some 2"
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    for (var folder in this.props.notes) {
      console.log(folder);
      this.state.arr.push(folder);
      this.setState({
        arr: this.state.arr
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        something
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Note: Here I'm including notes prop as default prop to give an idea about it's structure. In reality, it's coming from it's parent. But there's no problem there. I checked and I'm receiving the right prop.

Comment: your state should be defined in a constructor...

Comment: Can you `console.log(this.props.notes)` before the `for` loop and make sure it's set as you expect?

Comment: @MatthewG I did, the props is correct.

Comment: @eugene_sunic Any particular reason why? As I believe newer syntax allows us to define state outside, infact that is recommended.

Comment: @AkshayGupta can you share the value of `this.props.notes` as that may help identify the problem.

Comment: @AkshayGupta can you sandbox the code...

Comment: @eugene_sunic yes doing that right now

Comment: Hey, I'm having some trouble sand boxing this as my pc hangs when I open stack overflow's code editor. I made some changes though. It should be more clear now.

Comment: `this.state.arr.push` and `this.setState`, decide for local property or react's state management (suggesting the second ofcourse). Do setState outside of the loop, and fill a local variable, or just map your notes. Also, how / where are you rendering your component? Are you sure it is getting mounted?

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be setting the state as many times as `this.props.notes`, and by looking at your code, you don't even need the for loop, you can achieve the same result doing something like:

```
  componentDidMount() {
      this.setState((prevState) => ({
        arr: [...prevState.arr, ...this.props.notes]
      }));
  }
```

Comment: Not working. I updated the question to be more clear. Can you have a look again?

Comment: @AkshayGupta Probably because the expected datatype would be an array in notes (according to this answer), but you seem to have an unnecessary complex structure, you could do it through `...Object.keys( this.props.notes )` though

Comment: Wow! I had no idea there's a method for that. Thanks for that man. Might actually make my solution easier.

Comment: The idea behind my answer (as @Icepickle said in one of the comments) is to set the state only once

Comment: This answer actually made my code better. Infact I'm not using this piece of code anymore. Though I still don't understand why it wasn't logging anything in console.

Comment: Got it! Because the props weren't rendered. I wrote an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

props are passed to your constructor, you need to populate this.props there before you use them. Just add...

```
constructor (props){
     super(props);
     // Any other initialisation you need
}
```

to your class

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

It's not going inside the `for` loop because `this.props.notes` is empty. 
The component `NotesList` has not received props yet, because `ComponentDidMount` for a child runs before `ComponentDidMount` for a parent. The props that are coming to `NotesList` are fetched inside the parent's `ComponentDidMount`, something that I should've mentioned probably.

Comment: You should rather think if you really want to keep state & props in a child/parent relation? It doesn't give you lots of benefits from the code that was shown

Comment: @Icepickle I don't think I understand your point. Can you elaborate? Or maybe point me to the right direction?